# How to convert match patterns in extension manifests to Regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, glob

In my application manifest I have declared in the `content_scripts` the `matches` for valid URLs where the extension should be allowed to run

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.creoweb.com/data/", "*://*.creoweb.com/cp/*/history/","*://*.creoweb.com/user/*/panel/"],      
      "js": ["content_scripts/core.js"]
    }
  ]
```

In my code I have something like this:

```
const filter = {
  url:
  [
    {urlMatches: "*://*.creoweb.com/data/"},
    {urlMatches: "*://*.creoweb.com/cp/*/history/"},
    {urlMatches: "*://*.creoweb.com/user/*/panel/"}
  ]
}

function logOnCompleted(details) {
  console.log(`onCompleted: ${details.url}`);
}

browser.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(logOnCompleted, filter);
```

I think that the listener wants RegEx to work, in fact I'm not getting any console log output using this.

Comment: [glob-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-to-regexp) could be a nice way if you are able to use external dependencies

Comment: @youdateme I eventually converted them to RegEx but the listener is never firing.

Answer (score 0):

I published a module named `webext-patterns` that can generate a WebExtension-specific regex from patterns and globs. Other alternatives like `glob-to-regex` may not match the browser behavior (especially around slashes and `:/`)

- https://github.com/fregante/webext-patterns

Note however that regular expressions used by extensions for matching URLs are limited, they aren't full regexes, so that might be the reason why it doesn't work.

More info:

- https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/events/UrlFilter#urlmatches

Comment: Question is rather old so I don't know what excatly led me to abandon this approach and use a more canon RegEx `new RegExp('^https:\\/\\/www\\.linkedin\\.com\\/in\\/\.*\\/recent-activity\\/all\\/$').test($currentUrl)` so probably the `urlMatches` didn't like the `*` or something else, I really don't know.

Comment: Yes in your case it's better to just write regexes. I posted this information because the general question asks for _conversion,_ so it might be useful to future visitors.